# How to disable or hide WordPress.com as a social media login option for Jetpack Comments

Tags: comments, plugin-jetpack

I am looking for a method to hide or remove WordPress from the login options in Jetpack Comments.

I have tried adding `a#postas-wordpress {display:none !important}` to the theme's style.css, but no luck.

Here is a screenshot of the default comment form with Jetpack Comments enabled.

[image: Wordpress Jetpack Comments form]

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if it's best practice, but have you tried `visibility:hidden;`?

Comment: I tried that. No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Shines good find that its an iframe, i came up with this:

If you can get a HTML element in next to the iframe (so that its a sibling to the iframe) you could make the parent and the iframe position relative and this new element (we can call the new element blockie) position absolute. now make sure that the z-index of blockie is higher than the z-index of the iframe, then use css attributes "top" and "right" to position blockie over the logo

Example CSS:

```
.blockie-parent{
    position:relative;
}

.blockie-parent iframe{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}

.blockie{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    top: 140px;
    right: 69px;
    background:gray;
}
```

Change your theme's comments.php to follow this example:

```
<div class="blockie-parent">
    <div class="blockie"></div>
    <?php comment_form(); ?>
</div>
```

This will block the button. You may want to change "blockie" background colour to match the background of the comment box. I admit its not the nicest solution, but it does work!

Good luck Travis!

Comment: Thanks for this. While it may work, it's not really a proper fix. I gave you an upvote, but paid the bounty to Shines.

Answer (score 4):

The JetPack reply box is displayed as an iFrame, so you can't change the style of that section of the page (this prevents cross site scripting, which can be used nefariously).

To see where the iFrame begins, take a look at the source code of a page with the comment feature. You'll see something like with "iframe src="http://jetpack.wordpress.com/jetpack-comment/..."

Lastly, there's not a way to get rid of the iFrame (and still use JetPack comments), and [one of the developers states there aren't plans to get rid of it](http://jetpack.me/2012/06/14/jetpack-comments-now-available/#comment-2049).

Comment: Triple negative... that's incredible. *mind blown*

Comment: Is this change more direct?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
<style type="text/css" title="text/css">
a#postas-wordpress {display:none !important}
</style>
```

in footer.php, right before the `</html>` tag? You may have to load that extra CSS after all the other style sheets load in order to override them.

Or you can hit it with the jQuery hammer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#postas-wordpress").css("display", "none");
});
});
</script>
```

If you're on wordpress.COM, this may not be possible.